# Infragistics UltraWebGrid Tree Multilingual

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

When handling the Infragistics UltraWebGrid Tree view with

```
ClientSideEvents CellClickHandler="uwt_CellClickHandler"
```

it gives a client side error while changing the UI language to "French" .

```
"Method cannot be found , check method name error " is generated.
```

Any ideas Guys?

Comment: You can post your Problem in http://forums.infragistics.com/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't change the value for the CellClickHandler property when doing localization since it is the string name of the JavaScript function.